# Heroku Deployment Error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msilib'

Tags: python, django, heroku

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this error so I can deploy my app on Heroku?

Here's my requirements.txt file:

```
asgiref==3.5.2
dj-database-url==1.0.0
Django==4.1.1
django-extensions==3.2.1
django-on-heroku==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
psycopg2==2.9.4
psycopg2-binary==2.9.4
python-decouple==3.6
python-dotenv==0.21.0
sqlparse==0.4.2
tzdata==2022.2
whitenoise==6.2.0
```

When I run the instructions 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' at the command line I get the following error:

```
from msilib.schema import AdminExecuteSequence
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msilib'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is msilib a requirement in your project?   Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: from msilib.schema import AdminExecuteSequence this statement is causing the error kindly remove the same if it is not required.

Comment: Okay, well, do you actually use `msilib`? If so, why isn't it listed as a dependency?

Comment: Hi All,

1. My project is in Visual Studio for Windows, but Heroku, where I'm trying to host, is Unix based.  I am not specifying msilib as a requirement.  When I run the command mentioned above to migrate, I get the error.  I don't know why msilib is being requested and throwing an error.

2. In the bdist_msi.py file there is a line 'from msilib import schema, sequence, text'. 
 Should I delete this from the python file that is not part of my project, but for some reason is being called during my migration request?

3.  No I don't use mislib.  The process is calling it for some reason.

Comment: P.S. Sorry for my run on comment.  The way I typed it didn't get saved.  I just read how to make new lines and paragraphs, but I can't edit the comment after 5 minutes.

Comment: Here's a link to the full traceback error because it's 3771 characters so too long to post directly here: https://flic.kr/p/2nSqpgf  
If there is a better way to post something like a long traceback error please let me know.